# Hide a video file stored on website from chrome inspect

Tags: angular, google-chrome, video, inspect, web-inspector

I have my angular project and logged users can see a video on the homepage.
The video is included with a tag like:

```
video src='assets/video.mp4'
```

The problem is that if I go to the homepage and I am not logged, I use the chrome inspect and I can see the video on assets.
But I want it to be visible only if the user is logged in. Otherwise he cannot access to it.

Is there a way to block user access to a media like this?

Comment: Only on the server side, if you make this file accessible only for authorized users. If the file can be downloaded without authorization, there will be always one or other way to get it.

Comment: How to do this? My Angular app is client only, and I've put it into public_html file. I have not coded a server

Comment: Then you can't. There are some tricks you can use but they can't guarantee security. Everything that were sent to client is accessible on the client as you can guess.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the video is part of your Angular-app as asset it will be available in the users browser.

Security by just hiding sthg. is never secure. A common way for this is a request to an external video-source.

Comment: But that's not secure. If I request the external source with an embed, the embed code will be visible and so also the link for it

Comment: That's right. Use the RouterModule (https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate) to solve this. The best way is to use an external API to serve the video (Backend). For security reasons implement ideally OIDC/OAuth2 for identification and authorization.

Comment: This will avoid unnecessary traffic, too ;)